# Where to place my business logic when using redis as my core BD

Tags: redis, lua, business-logic, business-logic-layer

Ok, so I want to make a platform based on building feeds of news that I read from RSSs. And I want to ingest data to redis using kafka, and this data in redis will be also used by other services. So I was wondering that I should implement an API to interact to my redis BD so I do not have my business logic sharded between clients doing requests to redis, I have thought of implementing a REST API inside a server which will store the core business logic. BUT, could I use LUA scripting to do so and avoid this extra node in my architecture? I mean: instead of implementing a POST in an API REST that would implement the creation of a Feed in my redis BD, I would implement a lua script to do so. And when I need an outside server to create a Feed I will call directly this lua script. This way I will reduce the round trips needed to make a change in my BD but I don't know if it can be very problematic in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua script can't be set as a Rest Server in Redis as it can't get out of the sandbox and can't run the background.

You might want to check the Redis module [RedisGears](https://redisgears.io/) as it can run Python script and is not limited to the sandbox.

Another module you might want to check is [RedisRest](https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/RedisREST).